# Handling framesets with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome

i am working with Selenium and Python 3, using Chrome webdriver. I have this very basic html page with some framesets, the frame that what im working on is loaded after i click a menu on the side bar, after that the information is loaded in the right side frame but when i try to find it is unable to locate it, i try to get back to parent frame using `driver.switch_to.default_content()` but it takes me back to the main page where i have to click again to get the information loaded, this is the source code of the information page where the info is already loaded. In this case, i want to find the "Contenido" frame.

So the flow is login > click on sidebar menu > click again > select > get info loaded on right frame and try to locate from there, the problem is that i cannot switch to the frame that has the information on it.

Any is help is much appreciated! Here is the page src.

[html source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkEpI.png)

```
<frameset rows="79,*" cols="*" framespacing="0" name="parentFrame" frameborder="NO" border="0">
<frame src="gupprincipal.encabezado" name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<frame src="gupprincipal.forma_inicio" name="mainFrame">
</frameset>
<html><head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        </head>
<frameset cols="145,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" name="frs_frameMenu">
<frame src="gupmenug.menu_sistema?p_pidm_n=874816" name="Menu" scrolling="NO" noresize="">
<frame src="gupprincipal.contenido" name="Contenido" id="contenido">
</frameset>
<noframes name="nfr_farmeMenu"><body>
        </body></noframes>

</html>`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, and sorry for that, its just that i cant find what to do haha, will take this on count on future posts, thanks!